# Synchronous execution of code on event in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I have an event listener in Node JS, as shown below.

```
client.on('collect', async reaction => {
    await external.run(reaction, ...);
});
```

The function I called external.run returns a promise, and takes around 5 seconds to complete. If this event is triggered again while the previous trigger is still in execution (i.e before the 5 seconds it takes), it messes with my program.

Is there a way to wait for the previous execution to finish before running the new one?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds to me like you need some sort of queue that the requests will get sent to during client.on() and are processed as they arrive in order in the queue.

Comment: @MaciejKozieja I tried that, but it ends up being a little hacky, you have to use setTimeout if it's false. If it comes to it, I will use that.

Comment: `you have to use setTimeout if it's false` - if what's false? anyway, that code "pattern" makes no sense (I do realise what you're trying to communicate though)

Comment: @MikeCheel I was thinking of doing that, but I was struggling to come up with an implementation. Would you mind sending an example?

Comment: @JaromandaX The person I was replying to deleted their comment, they were suggesting a global boolean variable to keep track of if the function is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you want is called a Lock in other languages ... JS doesn't provide that mechanism natively, but its easy to write one yourself:

```
 const createLock = () => {
   let queue = Promise.resolve();
   return task => queue = queue.then(() => task());
 };

 const externalLock = createLock();

 client.on('collect', reaction => externalLock(async () => {
    await external.run(reaction, ...);
 }));
```

<sub>For sure this is only a contrived example, you might want to handle errors properly ... or you just use one of the libraries out there that do this</sub>

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, it executes the external.run function once, and stops running it after the first time.

Comment: Then the promise returned by `external.run` never resolves.

Comment: This should work fine, but it may be easier to understand if it wasn't wrapped up in a helper method. The mixture of `async/await` and `then` also adds a bit of confusion to those just learning promises. The idea is simple enough though, keep track of the promise from the last execution so that following executions can be applied to the promise chain in sequence.

Comment: what if there's a rejection?

Comment: @jaromandaX right, that could also be a possible reason ... but as I said *For sure this is only a contrived example, you might want to handle errors properly ... or you just use one of the libraries out there that do this*

Comment: @JonasWilms - my comment wasn't directed at your answer, since you did mention that in your answer :p it was more directed at "this should work fine" of the previous comment - it won't work fine if there's a rejection :D

Comment: @JonasWilms Yep, you're right, I forgot to resolve in a couple of cases. Thanks, works great.